# How do I use the LibreOffice Java API to get the result of a formula?

Tags: java, libreoffice

Let's say that the following formula is at A1 on Sheet1:

```
=IF($'Sheet 2'.A1>0,"Some Text","")
```

This does not work:

```
Object value = xCell.getValue();
```

What I am expecting is value to be "Some Text". Instead I get '0'.

How do I get the actual cell string value based on a condition in another sheet?

Comment: What about `.getString()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XCell getValue returns a float. What is needed is to get the content value (not the storage value i.e. the formula) of the cell.

```
XTextRange text = UnoRuntime.queryInterface( XTextRange.class, xCell );
return text.getString();
```